# FleetDB and Playbook modules are not loading due to a mysql issue?

Tags: mysql, security, ubuntu-18.04

I have recently started working with Security Onion as a home project and I have been having a consistent issue with MySQL server and Security Onion not wanting to work. I can't seem to find much about this issue on the internet as I have searched on it for about two weeks. I was attempting to remedy the situation through different means, like uninstalling security onion, docker, MySQL, and all other dependencies and starting the installation process over again and I keep running into the same issue.

What I am seeing from `sudo cat /root/sosetup.log` is an issue between `FleetDB` and `Playbook`. Mostly all modules are being successfully installed/loading into Docker, but here is a snippet from the SO setup log where the issue lies.

***I am using Ubuntu 18.04 

I have a static IP setup for the server I'm working on***

```
      ID: fleetdb
Function: mysql_database.present
    Name: fleet
  Result: False
 Comment: One or more requisite failed: mysql.so-mysql
 Started: 21:07:54.333399
Duration: 0.011 ms
 Changes:   

      ID: fleetdbuser
Function: mysql_user.present
  Result: False
 Comment: One or more requisite failed: fleet.fleetdb
 Started: 21:07:54.337203
Duration: 0.006 ms
 Changes:   

      ID: fleetdbpriv
Function: mysql_grants.present
  Result: False
 Comment: One or more requisite failed: fleet.fleetdb
 Started: 21:07:54.340117
Duration: 0.006 ms
 Changes:
```

and

```
      ID: create_playbookdbuser
Function: mysql_user.present
    Name: playbookdbuser
  Result: False
 Comment: MySQL Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.19' (110)
 Started: 21:08:07.936111
Duration: 261912.003 ms
 Changes:   

      ID: query_playbookdbuser_grants
Function: mysql_query.run
  Result: False
 Comment: MySQL Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.19' (110)
 Started: 21:12:29.849936
Duration: 131064.848 ms
 Changes:   

      ID: query_updatwebhooks
Function: mysql_query.run
  Result: False
 Comment: MySQL Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.19' (110)
 Started: 21:14:40.915454
Duration: 131071.339 ms
 Changes:   

      ID: query_updatepluginurls
Function: mysql_query.run
  Result: False
 Comment: MySQL Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.19' (110)
 Started: 21:16:51.987499
Duration: 131070.6 ms
 Changes:
```

So, this mostly looks like a MySQL server issue that I am having and I am not sure how to go about this. I have MySQL Server installed, through sudo apt-get install mysql-server and I am able to access it, this is what it brings back when I look for Users and Databases.

```
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+                                                                                      
| Database           |                                                                                      
+--------------------+                                                                                      
| information_schema |                                                                                      
| mysql              |                                                                                      
| performance_schema |                                                                                      
| sys                |                                                                                      
+--------------------+
```

Because of these modules failing, the Security Onion setup failed and came back with `Install had a problem. Please see /root/sosetup.log for details. A summary of errors can be found in /root/errors.log. Press OK to exit.`

Any and all help would be very appreciated, and if you have any questions about anything regarding hardware, software, etc, feel free to ask.

Thank you

---

### Update: This is where I am at now with this issue

I commented out the loopback address under `my.cnf` in `/etc/mysql` and that may have fixed most of the underlying issue, but I am now left with 3 playbook modules that were left 'unchanged' (broken, as I would put it). Here is the output from running `so-playbook-restart`:

```
    Function: mysql_query.run
      Result: None
     Comment: Database query_playbookdbuser_grants is not present
     Started: 16:25:17.691762
    Duration: 31.445 ms
     Changes:   

          ID: query_updatwebhooks
    Function: mysql_query.run
      Result: None
     Comment: Database query_updatwebhooks is not present
     Started: 16:25:17.723549
    Duration: 30.857 ms
     Changes:   

          ID: query_updatepluginurls
    Function: mysql_query.run
      Result: None
     Comment: Database query_updatepluginurls is not present
     Started: 16:25:17.754968
    Duration: 34.591 ms
     Changes:
```

Comment: mysql isues can be ssen in the error log, which is the first place to look

Comment: @nbk Checked error logs, the only thing it's giving me is what the comments under playbook and fleet are telling me, which is: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.19'. Not sure why it can't connect to it's own IP address. .19 is the static IP I have setup for this server.

Comment: the next part is the my.ini or cnf, see what is there weritten 127.0.0.1 for example

Comment: @nbk I've done some digging and fixed an error with mysql's port and the my.cnf had 127.0.0.1 but I commented out that line now and it seemed to fix most of the issue. The issue I am now left with is the `so-playbook` module loading, but leaving 3 parts unchanged due to some lingering database issue. I will update this post with that issue at the bottom.